# Flutter : Cant get Location using any package - Tried various packages - getLocation blocks

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have been struggling with this issue for a while and I just cant figure this out. I have tried using two different plugins however both of them seem to have issues. I tried using Flutter location plugin and geolocation plugi.I dont think its a permission issue.Apparently whenever I call the main methods which are asynch along with await. The asynch method never returns. These are the libraries that I used

**Library 1: [location 1.4.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/location/latest/)**

Now I added the package in my pubspec.yaml in the following way:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  progress_hud:
     git: https://github.com/LampeMW/progress_hud/
  crypto: any
  validate: "^1.6.0"
  json_annotation: ^0.2.4
  image_picker: "^0.4.1"
  after_layout: "^1.0.4"
  firebase_messaging: #0.2.1
  device_info: ^0.2.1
#  geolocator: '^2.0.1'
  location: 
    git: https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation.git/
```

and I am using it the following way

```
//This method blocks
  Map<String, double> location = await new Location().onLocationChanged().single;

//This method also blocks and never continues
  currentLocation  = await  myLocation.Location().getLocation();
```

Here is the output from my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.6.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.6.0 at /Users/admin/Flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 9299c02cf7 (8 weeks ago), 2018-08-16 00:35:12 +0200
    • Engine revision e3687f70c7
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.4.1, Build version 9F2000
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 24.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.4445.29

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Since the first library had issues I was advised to use this Library however this Library does the same thing (hangs when its methods are called)

**Update**

**Library 2: [geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator)**
In my pubspec.yaml I added the following

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
  http: "^0.11.3+16"
  crypto: any
  validate: "^1.6.0"
  json_annotation: ^0.2.4
  image_picker: "^0.4.1"
  after_layout: "^1.0.4"
  firebase_messaging: #0.2.1
  device_info: ^0.2.1
  geolocator: '^2.0.1'
```

This is the code I am using with geolocation

```
Future<Position> getLocationWithTimeout() async
{
    Position finalPos;
    var geo = new Geolocator();
    geo.forceAndroidLocationManager = true;
    return geo.getCurrentPosition().then((Position pos){
        finalPos = pos;
        return finalPos;
    }).timeout(new Duration(milliseconds: GPS_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL_SHARED),onTimeout: (){
        log.severe("$className : Timeout happened - while retrieving position");
        return null; //Returns null
    });
}
```

In Library 2 I set the timeout to 20 seconds and it just times out.
Any suggestions on how I can fix this ?

Comment: which error did you get ? could you put more code in your question (the method line)?

Comment: I did not get any exception. These methods just dont return

Comment: use this : await  myLocation.Location().getLocation(); before the onlocationChange method ,   check the logs .  Are you testing on simulator? device? ios/android?

Comment: i am testing on android emulator

Comment: - check permissions,   -check if you have a location on your emulator,   -open android studio and check the log from native platform

Comment: ok ill check that and post back in a little bit

Comment: I also tried that on an actual device. It still does the same thing

Comment: did you check your permissions? are you calling this method first?  currentLocation  = await  myLocation.Location().getLocation();  ?? did you check the logs?

Comment: it seems like that package is not being active, there are a lot of open issues, maybe you can use this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator

Comment: I tried geolocator too. That package is a little better. It works some times and mostly it blocks like this package. I am not sure why its either a hit or a miss.

Comment: Ill update the post using the package too.